# Как сделать работающий динамический js?

Tags: javascript

К примеру:

```
var scriptCode = '<script> function faf() { alert(123); }';
document.head.innerHTML = document.head.innerHTML + scriptCode;
```

При последующей попытке вызвать код функцию faf() пишет что функция не найдена. Как решить эту проблему? Сразу скажу что через внешний src, решение не подойдет.

Comment: на чистом `javascript` нужно или на `jQuery` ?

Comment: Вы что то пропустили `var scriptCode = '<script> function faf() { alert(123); }'` => `var scriptCode = '<script> function faf() { alert(123); }'</script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('x').addEventListener("click", function() {
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  var scriptCode = document.createTextNode("function faf() { alert(123); };");
  tag.appendChild(scriptCode);
  document.head.appendChild(tag);

});

document.getElementById('y').addEventListener("click", function() {
  faf();
});
```

```html
<button id="x">Click to set function</button><br>
<button id="y">Run function</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас уже есть кусок скрипта в строке и вам надо его выполнить - это тот самый момент когда надо вспомнить про существование `eval`:

```
var scriptCode = 'function faf() { alert(123); }';
eval(scriptCode);
faf();
```

Но тут есть тонкость: `eval` выполняет код в текущей области видимости, и если вы напишите так в некоторой функции - то `faf` станет локальной функцией, а не глобальной. Если вам нужна глобальная функция - надо либо запустить `eval` не напрямую:

```
window.eval('function faf() { alert(123); }');
```

Либо опубликовать `faf` в глобальном объекте после выполнения:

```
eval('function faf() { alert(123); }');
window.faf = faf;
```

Либо сразу записывать его туда:

```
eval('window.faf = function() { alert(123); }');
```

Также можно вспомнить про конструктор `Function`:

```
window.faf = new Function('alert(123)');
```